# how do I avoid geometries being cut off, because they do not fit the scale (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I want to plot predicted values of my regression model using R's ggplot. Due to the large standard errors my effect is not really noticeable:[image]

When I zoom in by adjusting the scale via `ylim(0,2)` It cuts of the standard errors... How can I avoid this happening?

[image]

Comment: The way to do this is with `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,2))` - that just magnifies the plot, whereas a straight `ylim` also removes out-of-range data

Answer (score 0):

As @AndrewGustar says, you can use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,2))`.

You can also use `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,2), oob = scales::squish)`. This is often prettier, and it works well for ribbons without an edge colour (as in your confidence ribbons); the only unfortunate part is that it takes lines that lie outside the plot range and forces them to lie along the edge of the plot window, which isn't too pretty.